# Can you make a REST call to a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch-api

Instead of calling a REST API on a server, make a rest call to a react js component.
For Example:

Call

```
import React from 'react';

function Post(props) {

    function fetchPost() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/fetch_post/${props.match.params.post_id}`,
            {
                method: "GET",
            }
        )
        .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                return res.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e));
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('returned: ' + res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        });
    }
  }
...
```

REST API from React Component:

```
import React from 'react';

function FetchPost(props) {
   return (
        // How do I return a json object (obviously using JSON.stringify)? This return expects an HTML element
    
    );
}

export default FetchPost;
```

Is this possible? I removed all of the non-important data.

Comment: do you mean within the same app, e.g. from another component for getting some data?

Comment: Rewind a bit.. what problem does this approach solve for you as there may be a better way of doing things. This seems at best an antipattern

Comment: @quirimmo yes, that's what I mean

Comment: @Squiggs I'm going to build out the server and api eventually, but this will be a temporary solution. I'm sure there are better ones, but upon researching this, I couldn't find any info pertaining to this subject. So, I'd be interested to see if this is possible, never seen anyone implement this.

Comment: That's mostly because it doesn't make a lot of sense. If you don't have a server, you don't need fetch calls, you just directly access the things you need. And you write those in a way that uses normal JS conventions (e.g. `fetchPosts`, not `FetchPosts`, it's a function, not a class) but structured such that you can swap out the code inside the function from direct data to a fetch call once you add a server (so remember to make your function `async` and then await that wherever it's used, so that swapping in a fetch in the future is basically trivial)